# What is it DNSQR?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

I looked for a script that send a DNS request. I found out a script using "DNSQR", but I'm not sure what is this command, and I didn't find a good documentation for it.
this is the entire command: `qd=DNSQR(qname="www.facebook.com")`.

this is the whole script:

```
 my_packet = sr1(IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/UDP(dport = 53)/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname=URL)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's open the source code:

```
class DNSQR(Packet):
    name = "DNS Question Record"
    fields_desc = [ DNSStrField("qname",""),
                    ShortEnumField("qtype", 1, dnsqtypes),
                    ShortEnumField("qclass", 1, dnsclasses) ]
```

where `ShortEnumField` and `DNSStrField` defined this way:

```
class ShortEnumField(EnumField):
    def __init__(self, name, default, enum):
        EnumField.__init__(self, name, default, enum, "H")

class DNSStrField(StrField):
    def i2m(self, pkt, x):
        x = x.split(".")
        x = map(lambda y: chr(len(y))+y, x)
        x = "".join(x)
        if x[-1] != "\x00":
            x += "\x00"
        return x
    def getfield(self, pkt, s):
        n = ""
        while 1:
            l = ord(s[0])
            s = s[1:]
            if not l:
                break
            if l & 0xc0:
                raise Exception("DNS message can't be compressed at this point!")
            else:
                n += s[:l]+"."
                s = s[l:]
        return s, n
```

So, it is a way to pack all this information into one element.

Also let's see what is `DNS` and what is `qd`:

```
class DNS(Packet):
    name = "DNS"
    fields_desc = [ ShortField("id",0),
                    BitField("qr",0, 1),
                    BitEnumField("opcode", 0, 4, {0:"QUERY",1:"IQUERY",2:"STATUS"}),
                    BitField("aa", 0, 1),
                    BitField("tc", 0, 1),
                    BitField("rd", 0, 1),
                    BitField("ra", 0 ,1),
                    BitField("z", 0, 3),
                    BitEnumField("rcode", 0, 4, {0:"ok", 1:"format-error", 2:"server-failure", 3:"name-error", 4:"not-implemented", 5:"refused"}),
                    DNSRRCountField("qdcount", None, "qd"),
                    DNSRRCountField("ancount", None, "an"),
                    DNSRRCountField("nscount", None, "ns"),
                    DNSRRCountField("arcount", None, "ar"),
                    DNSQRField("qd", "qdcount"),
                    DNSRRField("an", "ancount"),
                    DNSRRField("ns", "nscount"),
                    DNSRRField("ar", "arcount",0) ]
```